# Nodejs Typescript build returns Error: Cannot find module '.'

Tags: node.js, typescript

i'm using TypeScript with nodejs while my runs fine in dev mode and after i run to build the app it returns error of module not found '.'

[image]

Comment: Looks like a problem with relative pathing but you would need more code to confirm. In particular the import statement it is failing on.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look